# Type 2 and Type 3 combination

Tags: grammar

Does it sound weird to say:

> I would've punched him if I were you.

Instead of:

> I would've punched him if I had been you.

Is it okay to use either of these interchangeably?

Comment: The second would've in 'I would've punched him if I **would've** been you' is wrong & not good English. Did you mean 'I would've punched him if I **had** been you'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, you're absolutely right. Sorry for that mistake.